# WM_PAINT message is never delivered if Window is created with WS_POPUP style

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to create a window with no title bar using the **"WS_POPUP"** style and I also need to do some painting on the borders.

I'm implementing my drawing logic in **"WndProc"** when I receive the **"WM_PAINT"** message. However, it's never delivered.

I've tried messing around with styles but whenever WS_POPUP style is used, WM_PAINT is never delivered consistently.

**This is copied from the auto generated code when you create a new "Windows Desktop Application" project with Visual Studio Community 2019 with only one thing changed:**

**WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW --> WS_POPUP**

**Creating the window:**

```cpp
HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);
```

**Registering the window class:**

```cpp
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_WINDOWSPROJECT2));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_WINDOWSPROJECT2);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
```

**Message loop:**

```cpp
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
```

**Process Window messages:**

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps; // NEVER CALLED !!!
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I expect a WM_PAINT message to be delivered so I could do some painting. However, it's never delivered.

Comment: "I'm trying to create a window with no title bar using the "WS_POPUP" style and I also need to do some painting on the borders." - Doesn't the very definition of `WS_POPUP` mean no controls or borders?

Comment: @paxdiablo, From the [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms960010(v%3Dmsdn.10)) it just says "Creates a pop-up window.". I couldn't discern anything more from that sentence.

Regardless, I needed to use it to remove the titlebar. I want to be able to control the border but without creating a titlebar.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/window-features#pop-up-windows

Comment: There is a gawdawful bug in the project template code, it mixes up the CW_USEDEFAULT and 0 arguments for the x, y, width and height parameters.  That normally isn't noticeable, except when you change the style to WS_POPUP.  Its height is 0 so you can't see it and no paint gets generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will receive a WM_PAINT event on startup, if you modify the CreateWindow call, like this:

```
HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE, 
  0, 0, 800, 600, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);
```

You simply need to put some valid width and height. 
The next time you'll receive WM_PAINT though, will be when you [InvalidateRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-invalidaterect) your window. 
Or, for instance if you click the Show Desktop button (bottom-right) and restore your window (restoring from minimized).
Note, you won't receive WM_PAINT, when your window re-gains focus (alt-tab), unless you InvalidateRect it, like this:

```
case WM_ACTIVATE:
    InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
    break;
```